# NodeJS add element to Object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, object, mongoose

I need to add element to existing Object.

Exemple of Object (Mongoose):

```
param: { 
    hello: 'Olá Mundo PT '
}
```

And I need to add new element, ex :

```
params.param.set(JSON.parse('{"'+req.param('param')+'":"'+req.param('trans')+'"}'));

//And I tryed push

 params.param.push(JSON.parse('{"'+req.param('param')+'":"'+req.param('trans')+'"}'));
```

But nothing works...

Comment: this doesn't work?  params.param['foo'] = 'bar'

Comment: @user1389596 nope... 
`[Error: Invalid atomic update value for $__. Expected an object, received object]`

Comment: You need to be clearer, are you just trying to extend an object, or add something to the DB, and you're sure you don't have a cursor (what mongoose returns sometimes). Extending objects with other objects is a bit more tricky, you should look at how jQuery's `$.extend` does it etc.

Comment: @adeneo nope, It was an error of mongoose, I updated and now it works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a mongoose module problem. Updating helped.